# Python labeling code - remove empty values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4, python-parser

I'm a GIS technician who is (slowly) learning python. I'm using it to generate custom labels in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. I have a point layer with 10 fields but no point uses all 10. I'm trying to display **only** the fields that has a value.

I think part of the problem is that my table has  values, "none", or "0" listed in some of the fields. I've tried replacing every "empty" value with a null but I don't think python/Arc likes this.

I've attached pics of what I have and what I want.

[image: Examples and tables and code]

```
def FindLabel ([ELEV_OBS], [INVERT_D_1], [INVERT_D_2], [INVERT_D_3], [INVERT_D_4], [INVERT_D_5], [INVERT_D_6], [INVERT_D_7], [INVERT_D_8], [INVERT_D_9], [INVERT_D_10] ) :
    return ([ELEV_OBS] + "\n" + 
            [INVERT_D_1] + [INVERT_D_2] + "\n" + 
            [INVERT_D_3] + [INVERT_D_4] + "\n" + 
            [INVERT_D_5] + [INVERT_D_6] + "\n" + 
            [INVERT_D_7] + [INVERT_D_8] + "\n" + 
            [INVERT_D_9] + [INVERT_D_10] )
```

Comment: I just noticed I missed that you have the invert depth and bearing on the same line. Can you clarify one thing: are there any instances where there is a depth recorded but no bearing, or vice versa?

Comment: I think that there is always a bearing string after the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would suggest doing it:

```
def FindLabel ([ELEV_OBS], [INVERT_D_1], [INVERT_D_2], [INVERT_D_3], [INVERT_D_4], [INVERT_D_5], [INVERT_D_6], [INVERT_D_7], [INVERT_D_8], [INVERT_D_9], [INVERT_D_10] ) :
    labs = []
    for field in [[ELEV_OBS], [INVERT_D_1], [INVERT_D_2], [INVERT_D_3], [INVERT_D_4], [INVERT_D_5], [INVERT_D_6], [INVERT_D_7], [INVERT_D_8], [INVERT_D_9], [INVERT_D_10]]:
        if field:
            labs.append(field)
    return "\n".join(labs)
```

The code will iterate over each field and check if it has a Null value or not. If it's Null, it will skip, otherwise, it will add it's value to a list. Finally, it joins all of the list items to a single string, separating them by the \n for new line.

For this to work, you should standardize all your empty values to contain Null (do this with Field Calculator, use Python interpreter, and set the value to None to make the field show Null. Not very intuitive, but that's how it works.

To explain why this works, consider that the Null value in Python boolean expressions evaluates to the same as False.

In order to accommodate the issue of having the first field on its own line, and for fields thereafter combining the odd and even numbered fields, here is a modified version:

```
def FindLabel ([ELEV_OBS], [INVERT_D_1], [INVERT_D_2], [INVERT_D_3], [INVERT_D_4], [INVERT_D_5], [INVERT_D_6], [INVERT_D_7], [INVERT_D_8], [INVERT_D_9], [INVERT_D_10] ) :
    labs = []
    Labs_final = []
    for field in [[ELEV_OBS], [INVERT_D_1], [INVERT_D_2], [INVERT_D_3], [INVERT_D_4], [INVERT_D_5], [INVERT_D_6], [INVERT_D_7], [INVERT_D_8], [INVERT_D_9], [INVERT_D_10]]:
        if field:
            labs.append(field)
    labs_final.append(labs[0])
    for i in zip(labs[1::2], labs[2::2]):
        labs_final.append(" ".join(i))
    return "\n".join(labs_final)
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution, thanks! I ended up concatenating the fields in Excel and joining the table to my existing feature class.

Comment: Yup, that works too, depending on what else the data get used for, it could be an issue. I generally try to avoid duplicating data like that and making my fields only contain one type of information (invert depth, bearing). This way, it can be used for other things down the road, like system modelling, etc. And having the data in your table only once makes it easier to maintain.